# two images per row on mobile phone browser display (bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure a lot of you are familiar with the way the interface looks on windows phones by default, you often have rows of two tiles... or buttons, whatever you wanna call them.

I would like to apply such a look to my webpage when it's viewed in a mobile browser, using bootstrap 3. To illustrate:

[image] 
This is how it'd look on a non-mobile phone device

[image] 
And this is how it'd look on a mobile phone (at least, when it's in portrait mode). Obviously not all images would fit on the screen, but that's exactly how I want it.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you put each imgage in different column.

Comment: Use the bootstrap grid. Have each image in a div with the `col-xs-6` class. Adjust the padding to make sure it's close to edge to edge.

Comment: @JohnP thanks JohnP, I understand that much. However, now I've got 2 images per row regardless of the browser size. I need to have all images using the `col-**-2` class, except when the browser size is the size of a mobile browser. Then it should, indeed be `col-xs-6`. How do I achieve this? Or am I thinking in a very silly way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bootstrap grid and put each img in div for example.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
       <img.....>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, perfect. Didn't know you could do it like that. Thanks!